# Upper triangular matrix with big zero in lower triangular?

Tags: math-mode, matrices

I can represent an upper trapezoidal matrix say as shown below. I would like to replace all those zeros with a single big zero that spans across the low triangle rows and columns, and maybe also add a delimiter along the diagonal that clearly shows it is an upper diagonal matrix. How can I do that?

```
\newcommand\x{\XSolid}
%\newcommand\x{\ding{53}}
\begin{equation}
  \left(
    \begin{array}{*5{c}}
    \x & \x & \x & \x & \x \\
     0 & \x & \x & \x & \x \\
     0 &  0 & \x & \x & \x \\
     0 &  0 &  0 & \x & \x \\
     0 &  0 &  0 &  0 & \x \\
  \end{array}\right)
\end{equation}
```

Separate question ... why the `\x` command I define outputs `#` rather than the intended cross symbol? It outputs the same symbol `#` no matter if I use `\XSolid` or `\ding{53}`

UPDATE: taking the answer as input, I ended doing this:

```
\newcommand\x{\times}
\newcommand\bigzero{\makebox(0,0){\text{\huge0}}}
\newcommand*{\bord}{\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}}
\begin{equation}
  \left(
    \begin{array}{ccccc}
    \x    & \x       & \x    & \x    & \x \\ \cline{1-1}
    \bord & \x       & \x    & \x    & \x \\ \cline{2-2}
          & \bord    & \x    & \x    & \x \\ \cline{3-3}
          & \bigzero & \bord & \x    & \x \\ \cline{4-4}
          &          &       & \bord & \x \\ \cline{5-5}
  \end{array}\right)
\end{equation}
```

which produces this:

[image]

Comment: `\documentclass{article}\begin{document}\XSolid\end{document}` results in `! Undefined control sequence.`, thus I assume you are loading a package to define `\XSolid`? Which package/which version, please?

Comment: good question! I have no idea :D it is a large report and I have been adding packages as needed. As I understand `\XSolid` has been defined somewhere but I have no idea where exactly. Oh I think the package that defines `\XSolid` is TikZ

Comment: You could place a `\show\XSolid` in the preamble. When it is still undefined, it will print to the log "> \XSolid=undefined. ", when it is defined it will give the definition, and if the definition is changed (from X to #), it will give a changed definition. For a lot of packages this might be a lot of work to find which package (re-)defines it...

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

\[
    \left(
    \begin{array}{ccccc}
    1                                    \\
      & 1             &   & \text{\huge0}\\
      &               & 1                \\
      & \text{\huge0} &   & 1            \\
      &               &   &   & 1
    \end{array}
    \right)
\]  

\end{document}
```

[image]

or `\makebox(0,0){\text{\huge0}}` if you want to have the same line spacing.

Comment: perfect! good catch about the line spacing .. I was getting nervous about it :D then saw your timely edit :) perfect!

Comment: Instead of ``\makebox(0,0){...}`` You can use ``\smash{\text{\huge 0}}``. It also easier to insert in LyX which doesn't seem to support the ``\makebox(...)`` (width,height) option.

Answer (score 11):

Just in case : you might need repeated dots across the diagonal. Here is a ugly way to do so.

```
\newcount\dotcnt\newdimen\deltay
\def\Ddot#1#2(#3,#4,#5,#6){\deltay=#6\setbox1=\hbox to0pt{\smash{\dotcnt=1
\kern#3\loop\raise\dotcnt\deltay\hbox to0pt{\hss#2}\kern#5\ifnum\dotcnt<#1
\advance\dotcnt 1\repeat}\hss}\setbox2=\vtop{\box1}\ht2=#4\box2}
```

And an exemple (using amsmath, of course) :

```
\[\begin{pmatrix}
1\Ddot{12}.(6pt,-2pt,6pt,-5pt)&1\Ddot8.(9pt,2pt,6pt,0pt)&\quad&\quad&1\\
&&&&\\
&&&&\\
&&&&\\
&\mbox{\Huge 0}&&&\\
&&&&1\\
\end{pmatrix}\]
```

[image: \Ddot in action]

Comment: why don't you use `\ddots` and `\cdots` instead?

Comment: It is really painful to adjust various `\ddots` across lines & columns of the matrix and, anyway, these `\ddots` never join up properly.

Comment: One more note : the width of the various elements has some influence onto the column widths and line heights. The suggested macro gives a zero width & height to the repeated dots, while `\cdots` and `\ddots` give a non-zero width.

Comment: Is there also a non-ugly way to do this?

Comment: I don't know ! Do you have any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

With `{pNiceMatrix}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}

$\begin{pNiceMatrix}[left-margin]
\times & \times & \times & \times & \times \\
       & \times & \times & \times & \times \\
       &        & \times & \times & \times \\ 
\Block{2-2}<\Huge>{0}
       &        &        & \times & \times \\
       &        &        &        & \times \\
\CodeAfter
 \tikz \draw (2-|1) -| (3-|2) -| (4-|3) -| (5-|4) -| (6-|5) ;
\end{pNiceMatrix}$

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]